# Reuse wrapper layout

Tags: android

I have dozens ViewHolder that use a very similar layout. They all have in common the "wrapper", and the only thing that change is the content of the wrapper.

For example (wrapper_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...  >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/something"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <Button android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <!-- Only the content of this LinearLayout changes -->
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/something_else"
        android:orientation="horizontal" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        ...
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message_sender"
            tools:text="Jon Snow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to reuse this layout in common with all the ViewHolders and change only the content of R.id.container.

For now I'm using a ViewStub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.xxxx), but I was wondering if there is a better way, maybe only via XML.